# Python: requests has no attribute get after I successfully run the code

Tags: python, python-requests

I have created simple file, fetching url with requests python library, see the code. First time file one.py works just fine and gets the url, but after that i get **pycache** created in my dir and I am getting the following error, somehow referring to a completely different file from the same dir. Also, in **pycache** i can see one file email.cpython-36.pyc
with the following code:

```
3

?YÊ„@s&ddlZddlmZddÑZeÉdS)ÈN)⁄
BeautifulSoupcCs"tjdÉ}t|jdÉ}t|ÉdS)Nzhttp://clickaces.com/contact/zhtml.parser)⁄requests⁄getr⁄content⁄print)⁄html⁄bsobj©r    ˙&/Users/mclaren/Desktop/june12/email.py⁄fetching_urls
r)r⁄bs4rrr  r   r   r
⁄<module>s
```

file one.py:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fetching_url():

    html = requests.get("http://shakespeare.mit.edu/lll/full.html")
    bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
    print(bsobj.h3)

fetching_url()
```

Error:

```
 File "one.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/Users/mclaren/Desktop/june12/email.py", line 11, in <module>
    fetching_url()
  File "/Users/mclaren/Desktop/june12/email.py", line 5, in fetching_url
    html = requests.get("http://clickaces.com/contact/")
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: your code runs perfectly how many ever times I run in my system. seems like error is being raised in `/Users/mclaren/Desktop/june12/email.py` file. May be you need to consider looking into that file, if requests module is imported or not

Answer (score 5):

[`email`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) is a standard library package that `requests` indirectly depends on.  By having a file named `email.py` in the same directory as your script, you're preventing `requests` from using the real `email` package.  Rename, move, or delete `email.py`.